# How to make RPG animated text in C#?

Tags: c#, console

So I'm making a game in a C# Console Application and I am curious on how to do something like a animated text style like you see in RPG's for example. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737195/blink-text-in-c-sharp

Comment: This isn't exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33538527/display-a-image-in-a-console-application/33604540

Comment: Be more specific. We can only guess what you mean by "animated text style like you see in RPG's".

Comment: https://forums.unrealengine.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=32362&d=1427507365

Answer (score 1):

This function should do the trick:

```
static void SimulateTyping(string message, int delay = 100) {        //'delay' is optional when calling the function
    foreach (char character in message)                               //take every character from your string seperately
    {
        Console.Write(character);                                     //print one character
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(delay);                         //wait for a small amount of time
    }
}
```

You can also make it generic, to write more than just strings (int, float etc.):

```
static void SimulateTyping<T>(T message, int delay = 100) {
    foreach (char character in message.ToString())
    {
        Console.Write(character);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(delay);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's showing me an error: error CS5001.

Comment: It's showing me an error; Error CS5001

Comment: `using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace C_sharp_Testing
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        }

        static void SimulateTyping<T>(T message, int delay = 100)
        {
            foreach (char character in message.ToString())
            {
                Console.Write(character);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(delay);
            }
        }
    }
}
`

Comment: I copied your code into VS and it works without errors. Try to rebuild your solution or copy it into a new project.